# BABEL_TRANSFORM_ERROR. Property value expected type of string but got object

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, ecmascript-5

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6rEQ.jpg)

I used this tutorial https://www.vairix.com/tech-blog/server-side-rendering-ssr-of-create-react-app-cra-app-in-2020%C2%A0 and the following example github repo https://github.com/dariomac/poc-cra-ssr

My bootstrap.js, I use node.js v12 and tried all possible solutions in Google

```
require('ignore-styles');

require('@babel/register')({
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    //"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
    [
      "transform-assets",
      {
        "extensions": [
          "css",
          "svg"
        ],
        "name": "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
      }
    ]
  ]
});

require('./index');
```

Note: I have added this to plugins in bootstrap.js since babel was complaining

```
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    //"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having any trouble with Node v12.13.0 using your bootstrap.js code.

I even tried with an empty & clean CRA project and it works without any change. I've updated the code of the Github repo to the latest version of every dependency.

Please, test it and let me know if that solved the issue.

Comment: No problem, I switched away from your github repo in favor of this cool cli for SSR https://github.com/antonybudianto/cra-universal

Comment: It is way easier to configure and works easy with create-react-app